# Trying to select a single element in CSS and make it colored yet it doesnt work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make one line colored using html and css.

I gave the id to the li. I want to select (in html) and put a `#` in the css file yet it doesn't work. Any ideas why?

link to html screenshot: https://gyazo.com/9a628fd411837433435248cfb153b814

link to css screenshot: https://gyazo.com/517e05b82e615218241cfc140a309ccf

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add your code rather with copy/paste than as picture. Please see [*How to ask?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you post your code in the question rather than as a screenshot. But anyway it looks your selector is malformed, it should be a curly braces pair:

```
#special {
    ...
}
```

You appear to have }} instead.

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache? Assuming that your CSS file paths are correct, it will work; although it mightn’t look the greatest.

Comment: alright i figured it out, the problem was that css and html were not connected for some reason, they were in the same place yet not connected. the problem fixed it self when i moved them both to the desktop. thanks for the help dude